# disable format for warning prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

My setup runs eslint with prettier to autoformat errors when possible.

However, I only want to format rules that I configured as "error", not rules I configured as "warning" as autoformatting those can break the code.

Is there a way to configure prettier in a way to do that?

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue does not seem to be related to Prettier. I am not using it and I have the same issue. I suspect it is something to do with Eslint or VSCode itself.